# getting error when trying to connect to a database using JDBC and Eclipse for Android

Tags: android, eclipse, sql-server-2005, jdbc

I'm trying to connect to a database from my android using JDBC and Eclipse IDE and Java

this is the code I wrote

```
package Android_SQL.Package;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Driver;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.util.Properties;

import Android_SQL.Package.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.util.Log;

public class Android_SQLActivity 
extends Activity 
implements OnClickListener
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button My_Button = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        My_Button.setOnClickListener(this);        
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        (new Thread(new Runnable() 
        {
            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                // Connect
                try {               
                    String cs = "jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.0.29:1433;databaseName=ODB0336;user=sa;password=savage";
                    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");        
                    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(cs);
                    //String sql="insert into Categories(CategoryName, Description) values(?,?)";
                    String sql="insert into Colors(ColorId, ColorEName, ColorName) values(?,?,?)";
                    PreparedStatement prepared = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                    prepared.setString(1, "ABCD");
                    prepared.setString(2, "ABCDEF");
                    prepared.setString(2, "XYZ");                   
                    prepared.executeUpdate();           
                } catch (Exception e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.i("Error", e.getMessage());
                }

            }
        }
        )
        ).start();                      
    }
}
```

but I'm getting the following exception when i connect :

"com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)"

how to fix it? what is the problem.

the JDBC version is : Microsoft SQL Server JDBC Driver 3.0

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Don't USE JDBC concept for android Applicatins. JDBC is meant for web and networking applications not for mobile application development.

Here is the link for learning Database connection in android

[DB EXAMPLE 1](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/)

[DB EXAMPLEV2](http://vimaltuts.com/android-tutorial-for-beginners/android-sqlite-database-example)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply but this is not what I'm looking for...I'm not looking to store any database inside the android device...all i need is to connect to remote SQL Server using it is IP Address then start fetching data and apply changes.

JDBC is not only for web and networking applications. it is the way Java connects to Datasource like SQL Server....!!!

Comment: i need to connect my android device with Microsoft SQL Server 2005 using JDBC

Answer (score 1):

Look at this example you will know how to connect remote database :

[Example 1](http://webdesignergeeks.com/mobile/android/android-login-authentication-with-remote-db/)

Comment: i need to connect to database directly not by using php service or any other services...

Comment: If you want to connect DB server directly, you the hostname of the DB server